# Alternating row alignment in Xamarin's ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, layout

I'm working on a messenger module for an existing mobile app - think of it as a bare-bones Whatsapp - and having no prior experience with Xamarin I'm having trouble rendering rows with text (the messages themselves) while alternating alignment to the left or right, which mirrors the behaviour found in most messengers where this alignment depends on whether the user is the sender or receiver of a message. I tried to combine a couple of solutions to similar problems I found around the web, but ultimately I hit a dead end.

Here's my latest failure. Code irrelevant to this question has been ommited. Bear in mind that a `ChatItem` refers to every individual chat page in my scope:

**ChatItemView.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding chatItem.Messages}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Appearing="Cell_OnAppearing">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Body}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="{Binding CellAlignment}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

`HorizontalOptions="{Binding CellAlignment}` is the key here, as it seems the preferred method of doing this kind of stuff. But it doesn't work as intended in a `ListView`. Or at least, not in the manner I'm approaching it. Also notice that I'm using an event handler for `ViewCell` `Appearing` event.

**ChatItemViewModel.cs**

```
public class ChatItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ChatItem chatItem { get; set; }
    public LayoutOptions CellAlignment { get; set; }

    public ChatItemViewModel(ChatItem chatItem)
    {
        Title = chatItem.Name;
        this.chatItem = chatItem;
    }
}
```

**ChatItemView.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ChatItemView : ContentPage
{
    private ChatItemViewModel model;
    private ChatItem chatItem;
    private int rows;

    public ChatItemView(ChatItem chatItem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.chatItem = chatItem;
        model = new ChatItemViewModel(chatItem);
        BindingContext = model;
        rows = 0;
    }

    public void Cell_OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chatItem.Self == chatItem.Messages[rows].Sender)
            model.CellAlignment = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        else
            model.CellAlignment = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
        rows++;
    }
}
```

I even removed the conditional in my `Cell_OnAppearing` method, where its implementation consisted only of `model.CellAlignment = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;` but it doesn't matter, as my text is perpetually aligned to the left. I ran out of brain juice so as I go home tonight, I can only hope the StackOverflow Gods might help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thought was implementing an [`IValueConverter`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/data-binding/converters/):

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
  <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Label Text="{Binding Body}" HorizontalOptions="{Binding IsSender, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

but a [`DataTrigger`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/) might do ; not shown: implementation of `IsSender` property:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Body}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
  <Label.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsSender}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check your suggestions and let you know what I come up with

Comment: I had to move some stuff around but all-in-all, DataTrigger works like a charm. Many thanks Benl!